# Xamarin Forms Android Project build but does not deploy to Device

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Hi guys I'm trying to debug the Evolve App using Visual Studio 2015.
I have built all the relevant projects successfully but when I go to debug I get an error.
I looked into the error and found that it has to do with the jarsigner and the debug.keystore.

I'm relatively new to Xamarin so my knowledge of the keystore is quite limited but I understand that it is used to sign an app during development.
I have looked in the file specified and there is no file.

Do I have to give the app the keystore a alias and password manually or am I missing a debug.keystore completely?

Apologies if I'm totally off the mark here as I'm still getting familiar with Xamarin.

here is the stack trace:

```
jarsigner error: java.lang.RuntimeException: keystore load: C:\Users\dummy\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\debug.keystore (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android apps need to be signed with keystore, this is normally generated when Xamarin.Android is first installed. Not sure why you dont have it.

You can create a keystore which will be used to sign the apps by using following command:

```
keytool.exe -list -v -keystore "%LocalAppData%\Xamarin\Mono for Android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

You can find more information [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/MD5_SHA1/#Windows).